# Need to get readable folder name using iimap_getmailboxes php

Tags: php, imap

I use below code to get folder list in gmail and kakao.com. This is working fine in gmail but not working in kakao.com.

```
$mbox=imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "user", "pass");
$list = imap_getmailboxes($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "*");
$mailbox=null;
$mailbox_name='';
$number=0;
foreach ($list as $key ) {
echo $key->name; echo "*";
}exit;
```

Here in Gmail I got result like :
*Inbox
*Sent Messages
*Drafts
*Spam and may more

Code for kakao.com

```
$mbox=imap_open("{imap.kakao.com:993/imap/ssl}", "user", "pass");
$list = imap_getmailboxes($mbox, "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "*");
$mailbox=null;
$mailbox_name='';
$number=0;
foreach ($list as $key ) {
echo $key->name; echo "*";
}exit;
```

Here in kakao.com got result like :
*Inbox
*Sent Messages
*Drafts
*???8?????h

Can I got all folder name as readable folder name ?
Let me know it is possible or not.

Comment: And what _is_ the actual name of that folder that shows up as `???8?????h`? Currently not sure whether this might simply be a character encoding problem, too little info.

Comment: I just edited the question.
I think this is character encoding problem, I need to decode this to folder name.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Probably. But if you don't know which encoding it is in, then you will have to do some trial & error, until you find the proper one. I'd start with `imap_utf7_decode` (which decodes into `ISO-8859-1`, so if your page is in UTF-8, then you will have to encode the result as that again, before you output it into that context.)